# gtk height_for_width leading to unreasonable window heights for given width due to smaller minimum width

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I am implementing a container which algins its children in a row and does kind of a linebreak when there is no horizontal space left. Thus, the required height depends on the available width. For larger widths, more content fits in one line and less lines are needed leading to less height. For smaller widths, less content fits in one line and more height is needed.

I subclassed the container and implemented the needed logic. The minimum width of the container is set to the minimum width of the widest child which would display one extreme case where there are stacked lines, some of them with only a single child inside them.

The problem is as follows: The window displaying the container has a very large height, for some cases even larger than my monitor. I am able to resize the window except that I cannot decrease the width. It turns out that the documentation for height-for width geometry management says:

> Next, the toplevel will use the minimum width to query for the minimum height contextual to that width using gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width()[...]. The minimum height for the minimum width is normally used to set the minimum size constraint on the toplevel (unless gtk_window_set_geometry_hints() is explicitly used instead).

Thus, the behaviour is expected as the window uses the height for the minimum width as its minimum height leading to the previously mentioned extreme case. This seems to be counterintuitive as in my case and an example used in the documentation (textflow in labels) the height will be maximal when the width is minimal vice versa. Only when actually allocating the available space, gtk considers to assign smaller heights when a larger width allows that. Even when using high widths in the window's default size and size request only the minimum width of the container is considered to derive the required height of the window.

The documentation already somehow contains a workaround, namely the geometry hints. But this seems to be a verbose and static way of sizing the window when the default width of the window together with the height-for-width-function could theoretically be used to easily determine the size of everything. The size-allocation already works as intended, only the size-negotiation cancels the benefits the height-for-width function could bring here. Is there any *nice* way of implementing the functionality required to fix the window sizing?

Comment: You could use/take inspiration from [GtkFlowBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFlowBox.html)?

Comment: @nielsdg The problem about GtkFlowBox is that it aligns its items in implicit columns which is not acceptable for my application. This behaviour would lead to small children becoming very large when there is a wide child in another row above or below. Also, while the FlowBox seems to use height-for-width-sizing in the matching orientation i cannot find the actual implementation of it inside gtkflowbox.c

Comment: The problem with GtkFlowBox is the reason why I am writing my own container, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64617479/gtkflowbox-do-not-align-in-columns-using-horizontal-orientation. After implementing a rather nasty workaround now I tried to write the container to provide it as answer to this older question also.

Comment: You might take a look at some code in Geary that does what you want: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/geary/-/blob/mainline/src/client/components/components-reflow-box.c

Comment: @JamesWestman As far as I see, Geary does not handle the problem I described the way I was searching for. But as it nearly does what I was searching for, I want to thank you for that hint. I will refer to your idea in my old post regarding the GtkFlowBox.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as there is no intended workaround for this problem the way I searched for. The gtk size negotiation goes from bottom to top when requesting sizes and top to bottom when allocating. Thus, my container has no way of knowing how much width its parent could assign to it.

I solved the problem by adding a property which defines the minimum of children per row. This can be used to increase the minimum width and therefore decrease the minimum height. I only use it for the minimum width calculation while actually ignoring it doing the real size allocation which only is a minor detail I will document.

This documentation will be part of the code example I will provide as an answer to my [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64617479/gtkflowbox-do-not-align-in-columns-using-horizontal-orientation) which was about implementing a FlowBox with the behaviour described above.